# intercept DialogFragment dismiss inside activity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

I have an activity

```
public class ShowFileActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

and when occours some event, this class call a DialogFragment

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends DialogFragment
```

that is a simple confirm dialog (with "dismiss" and "ok" button). 
If user press dismiss button, i call

```
dismiss()
```

and come back to ShowFileActivity.
Else, if user press ok, after made some operations, after call dismiss on dialog, i would go back to parent activity of ShowFileActivity.
There's a way to do it? Does DialogFragment launch any event to his parent view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is to call a method of the containing activity from inside the fragment.
As per any other fragment, you can call getActivity() which returns the containing activity.

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    ShowFileActivity parent = (ShowFileActivity) getActivity();
    parent.doWhateverYouWantWhenDialogDismissed();
}
```

Another (more fancy) approach would be to use an event bus such as [otto](http://square.github.com/otto/) or [greenrobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).